# Parallel active optimization

Tags: optimization, sampling, parallel

I'm trying to optimize an expensive function for which I can choose sample points. The difficulty is that many function evaluations may be computed in parallel, taking varying amounts of time. I don't know which keywords to search for to find existing literature(/implementations).

So at a time, I might have already computed function values at 18 points, with 15 still being computed, and I want to start evaluating the function another point. Without the running jobs, I could make a model and find which next point might provide the most information. But now, I need to somehow tell the model that there are also 15 points for which I don't have values, but near which I don't want to evaluate the function.

Specifically, I'm looking for something with minimal assumptions and no gradient information. But I'll be happy if I just know the keyword(s) to search for. (I can come up with several hacks to that kind of work, but I wonder if there is any 'real' solution).

---

*For illustration, say every column is a function evaluation point and every row is a timestep in the below ascii-figure. An `X` means the evaluation is still being computed and a `*` in the bottom row means it's done. A new evaluation starts as soon as an old one terminates, with others still busy.*

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXX
 XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXX
 XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXX
 XXXXXXXXXXX X  XXX X
 XXXX XXXXXX X  XXX XX
 XXXX XXXXXX X  XXX  XX
 XXXX XXXXXX X  XXX  XX
 XXXX XXXXXX X  XXX  XX
 XXXX XXXXXX X  XXX  XX
 XXXX X XXXX X  XXX  XXX
 XXXX X XXXX X  X X  XXXX
 XXXX X XXXX X  X X  XXXX
  XXX X XXXX X  X X  XXXXX
  XXX X XXXX X  X X  XXXXX
  XXX X XXXX X  X X  XXXXX
  XXX X XXXX X  X X  XXXXX
  XXX X XX X X  X X  XXXXXX
  XXX   XX X X  X X  XXXXXXX
  XXX   XX X X  X X  XXXXXXX
  XXX   XX X X  X X  XXXXXXX
  XXX   XX   X  X    X XXXXXXXX
  XXX   XX   X  X    X XXXXXXXX
  XXX   XX   X  X    X XXXXXX XX
  XXX   XX   X  X    X XXXXXX XX
  XXX   XX   X       X XXXXXX XXX
  XX    XX   X       X XXXXXX XXXX
**  ****  *** ******* *      *
```

*Each time an evaluation completes, how to choose the next point to evaluate, given several complete and several incomplete evaluations?*

Comment: A producer consumer model may be worth searching on

Comment: Could you give an indication of how long an evaluation takes? Evaluation time influences proposals quite a bit

Comment: @JanvanderVegt Between minutes and hours. I guess doing it parallel more important for the hours case.

Answer (score 1):

[SMAC](https://automl.github.io/SMAC3/stable/index.html#) has a parallel version available.

I'm not sure it handles the single runs as you want, but it sounds strange to me if it don't. Give a try!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a parallelized Gaussian process regression model. The next points to query in this framework are given by the posterior extrema or those of [maximum expected improvement](http://people.orie.cornell.edu/pfrazier/Presentations/2011.11.INFORMS.Tutorial.pdf). [Here's an implementation](https://github.com/arikcj/pgpr).

Comment: I don't quite grasp yet how this deals with points that are being evaluated, but I'll have a look at the code, thanks!